# Is it possible to submit/put or publish Share Point Modern Apps (SPFx) web parts in the Microsoft Store?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts

Is it possible to submit/put or publish Share Point Modern Apps (SPFx) web parts in the Microsoft Store ? The solution package (.sppkg) build with SharePoint framework .

What is the Microsoft announcement or plans or way out to submit any Modern Share Point Apps (SPFx).Is there any way out or possibilities ?

Answer (score 0):

No, only traditional appWebs are allowed. However, for some special cases, Microsoft catalog team might include your app in the modern view directly.

Happened to me for 1 of my apps